# Why are the conjugacy classes of a finite group (where the conjugacy classes all commute) in the stabilizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Hi I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_r$ representatives of conjugacy classes of the
>   finite group $G$ such that they all commute with each other. Show $G$
>   is abelian. Hint: some $g_i's$ determine $Z(G)$.

I have found a solution [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/if-a-set-of-conjugacy-class-representatives-of-a-finite-group-commute-pairwise-the-group-is-abelian/). But I do not understand why the following statement:

> In particular, $g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_r \in \mathsf{stab}(g_i)$ for all $i$
>   under the conjugation of $G$.

Here is my thought process so far...

We want to show that $g_i\cdot a=a$ for $a\in G$ in order to show that an arbitrary $g_i\in\mathsf{stab}(g_i)$. We also know that $g_ig_j=g_jg_i$ for all representatives of the conjugacy classes.

Notice $g_1\cdot a = g_1(a)g_1^{-1}$. And this is where I get stuck. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $g, h \in G$ commute, then $g \in \mathrm{stab}(h)$ if $G$ acts on itself by conjugation (and vice versa, i.e. $h \in \mathrm{stab}(g)$). To see this, note $g \cdot h = ghg^{-1} = (gh)g^{-1} = (hg)g^{-1} = h(gg^{-1}) = h$. In fact, $\mathrm{stab}(h)$ consists exactly of elements of $G$ which commute with $h$. Indeed, we have already shown that the element of $G$ which commute with $h$ belong to $\mathrm{stab}(h)$. Now suppose $g \in \mathrm{stab}(h)$. Then $g \cdot h = ghg^{-1} = h$, so $ghg^{-1}g = hg$, i.e. $gh = hg$.

Comment: I do not know if $g$ commutes with $h$ though...only the representatives of the conjugacy classes. Is this argument this valid?

Comment: @jm.byrnes: I am saying that *in general, if* $g$ commutes with $h$, then $g \in \mathrm{stab}(h)$. In your *particular case*, you know that $g_{1}, \ldots, g_{r}$ commute with $g_{i}$ for all $i$ a priori, so $g_{1}, \ldots, g_{r} \in \mathrm{stab}(g_{i})$ by the argument above. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Ohhh I see it. I am only looking at the stabilizer for an arbitrary $g_i$ and all $g_{1}, \ldots, g_{r}$ commute with $g_i$, which makes the statement true. I was trying to find the stabilizer of any element of $G$. That's where messed up. Thank you! It was a bad application of the definition on my part.

Comment: @jm.byrnes: you got it! Happy to help.